# playframework 2.1.x: starting a plugin programmatically

Tags: scala, playframework

Is there a way to start a plugin programmatically on Play 2.1.x (Scala)?

I'm developing a Play module that has several features that can be activated via plugins. For some of these plugins I'd like to start a default if none is running.

This is a simple example of use:

```
import play.api.Application
import guardbee.services.ServiceCompanion
import play.api.PlayException
import play.api.Plugin

trait TokenProvider {
  def generate(): String
}

object TokenProvider extends TokenProvider {
  import play.api.Play.current

  def delegate(implicit app: Application): TokenProvider = app.plugin[TokenProvider]    match {
    case Some(plugin) => plugin
    case _ => throw new PlayException("TokenProvider Error", "The TokenProvider has not been initialized!")
  }

  def generate(): String = delegate.generate
}
```

As you can see if any plugin is registered, the call generates an exception. I would like (in this case) to do something like this:

```
def delegate(implicit app: Application): TokenProvider = app.plugin[TokenProvider] match {
  case Some(plugin) => plugin
  case _ => //Start the default and return
}
```

**UPDATE**

It is correct/safe, in your opinion, to do this:

```
import play.api.Play.current
lazy val delegate: PasswordProvider = current.plugin[PasswordProvider] match {
  case Some(plugin) => plugin
  case _ => new BcryptPasswordProvider(current)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your updated lazy val you are moving the error (of no implicit application) from the compiler into runtime and on top of that it may give you problems in your tests.

Your object TokenProvider will be initialized in the first test that accesses it and then live with the JVM, keeping its reference to the first application instance, regardless if the play app starts or stops during your tests.

Maybe you could make the logic that chooses a plugin in itself so that it will be bound to app lifecycle? That way you could lazy-create the default instance without any problems.

Comment: So if I understand you suggest to make a plugin "broker of other plugins" and every time I need a delegate I ask to him, right?

Comment: Yeah, exactly, and the broker of other plugins would hold the default, if needed. You could then hide the fact that there is such a broker plugin from the consuming/client code with a method with an implicit Application just like in your example code. Of course you would also have to make sure to always add it to the plugins config file, which might be show stopper in your particular use case.